# FSCalendar: Get Start and End date of current view

Tags: swift3, fscalendar

How can I get current calendar start and end date?

From the screenshot, I need to get Sep 24 2017 and Nov 4 2017..

thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTwZB.png)

Answer (score 3):

```
var dateArray = [Date]()
for cell:FSCalendarCell in calendar.visibleCells() {
  if cell.isPlaceholder {
    dateArray.append(calendar.date(for: cell)!)
  }
}

calendar.select(dateArray.min())
calendar.select(dateArray.max())
```

Comment: I tried doing your suggestion but I got Start: `Optional(2017-08-26 16:00:00 +0000)` and End: 
`Optional(2017-10-03 16:00:00 +0000)`

Comment: Yes, that's how it would get printed. Please try selecting the dates in the calendar. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can see the first and last visible date

```
let startDate: Date?
let endDate: Date?
if self.calendar.scope == .week {
    startDate = self.calendar.currentPage
    endDate = self.calendar.gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: startDate)
} else { // .month
    let indexPath = self.calendar.calculator.indexPath(for: self.calendar.currentPage, scope: .month)
    startDate = self.calendar.calculator.monthHead(forSection: (indexPath?.section)!)!
    endDate = self.calendar.gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 41, to: startDate)
}
```

[The answer is originally mentioned in this thread](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues/503)